# Combined 2 array data

Tags: php

I want to do something like bellow using php:

```
$turl=array(trim($params->get('c2')));
$tname=array(trim($params->get('cn2')));
```

and want to display each `$turl` with each `$tname`.

I tried like this:

```
$result=array_combine($turl,$tname);
print_r($result);
```

but given result as:

```
Array ( [http://184.107.144.218:8282/,http://184.107.144.218:8082/] => ABC Radio,AHH Radio )
```

But I want like this:

```
Array ( [http://184.107.144.218:8282/=> ABC Radio,
http://184.107.144.218:8082/=> AHH Radio )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want to use a code similar to this:

```
$turl  = explode(',',trim($params->get('c2')));
$tname = explode(',',trim($params->get('cn2')));

$result=array_combine($turl,$tname);
print_r($result);
```

The error seems to be into the $turl and $tname arrays creation as array combine should work as intended

Obviously I would add several checks, as, for example, Have the two arrays the same size?

***Addendum***
In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794274/combined-2-array-data/9794405#comment12497632_9794405) you give me a specimen of what `$params->get` returns if called with parameters 'c2' and 'cn2'.

```
$params->get('c2')="hoicoimasti.com,google.com" 
$params->get('cn2')="hoicoi,google".
```

The example code I gave you do what required, or at leas what I was thinking you are trying to obtain. A different code with a different result is:

```
$turl  = explode(',',trim($params->get('c2')));
$tname = explode(',',trim($params->get('cn2')));

$result=array_map(function($x,$y){return $x.','.$y;},$turl,$tname);
print_r($result);
```

or, if you want to obtains a single string:

```
$result=join(',',array_map(function($x,$y){return $x.'=>'.$y;},$turl,$tname));
print_r($result);
```

You can obtain any desired result modifying one of the previous example.

To encase the results in an option you need a slight variation of the array_map user function:

```
$result=join("\n",array_map(
    function($x,$y){
        return "<option>$x=>$y</option>";
    },
    $turl,
    $tname
));
print_r($result);
```

**PHP < 5.3 version**
Put this function declaration somewhere in the global scope

```
function formatOption($x,$y){
    return "<option>$x=>$y</option>";
};
```

and then your code will become:

```
$result=join("\n",array_map( 'formatOption', $turl, $tname));
print_r($result);
```

If possible I won't clutter the global namespace with function like *formatOption*,
but when anonymous function are not available

**Reference**:

- [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map)
- [join](http://www.php.net/join)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes two arrays are same size. But your code not working. Output like: Array ( [Array] => Array ( [0] => ABC Radio [1] => AHH Radio ) )

Comment: You don't need the `array()` on the first two lines ... `explode` returns an array ...

Comment: @jibon57 You should post some other details to have a better answer. A dump of $params->get('c2') and 'cn2', for example.

Comment: @Eineki Thanks again. I want to put some url in $params->get('c2') & site name in $params->get('cn2') & want to join with each url with the site name. For example if $params->get('c2')="hoicoimasti.com,google.com" then $params->get('cn2')="hoicoi,google". I want to get result combined like $result=$url.$name

Comment: @Eineki thanks for your help. It's working just nice. Would you please help me little more ? I want to add <option> tag in each line. For example from your code i got output like this: "hoicoimasti.com=>hoicoi,google.com=>google". I want this <option>hoicoimasti.com=>hoicoi</option> <option>google.com=></option>. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Eineki  problem again ! I have was checking your code this morning in php 5.2.7 environment & it show me some error like :"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' " . But this was working nice in php 5.3.8 environment. Plz help me & thanks in advance

Comment: @jibon57 Anonymous function are supported from php5.3 onward. You will need to change the code in order to let it work in previous php versions.

Comment: @Eineki thanks thanks ......you are great. I was creating a module for joomla. you can see it http://www.hoicoimasti.com/52-extension/joomla/168-hoicoi-radio.html

Comment: @jibon57 I'm pleased you appreciate my help. I will check your plugin and, if you don't mind, I'll send my thought on it later. If you appreciate our community too, you should contribute accepting answers and/or voting them. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation